# Scooter on Crete, Greece

Tags: greece, motorcycles, crete

I wanted to explore the far western part of Crete, namely Balos Beach, Falassarna and Elafonissi, from Kissamos by scooter. However, I get conflicting information here on the island. Some say that the 50cc scooter is useless when it has to take two people uphill, and that Balos beach is a no-go with a scooter, and some say it's fine. Any thoughts on this, and on exploring Crete by scooter?

Comment: I'd guess that not all 50cc scooters are created equal.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on quality of scooter, skill in driving it and your determination.

1. Yes, small scooters are next to useless on steep mountain roads, especially with two persons on them. Probably you will get to your destination but it will be painful.
2. Road to Balos Beach is an unpaved one. Generally good idea with scooter is to keep yourself to asphalt roads and ride on dirt only really short distances. If you want to travel longer distances on dirt roads try to get scoooter with 'no excess'.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this question is still open but in general it is more safe to visit such places with either bus service or renting a car. The bus service www.e-ktel.com has many routes (nope, I don't work for them, just a local). In general a 50cc is a big no for national highways etc. As for quad bikes I agree, they can be fun to ride in the cities & suburbs but other than that again, not really, many accidents happen especially with those who are not experienced with. *No offense, a biker myself, just have seen few accidents. Hope I helped a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be riding on rough terrain, a better (and probably safer) option would be to hire a quad bike. Most places that hire scooters in Greece also do quads. If you plan on going up steep hills you'll need one of the larger engine models, they will typically do a range of sizes.

Another advantage is that because they have more than 2 wheels, they are not classed as motorcycles under EU vehicle classification, so as long as you have a B1 licence you are not restricted on power.

Comment: Quadbikes are notorious for not being safe! For some reason people seem to thing they are inherently safe and forgo safety precautions. If you're going to ride a quadbike you have to be serious about safety.

Comment: @hippietrail and scooters would be any safer on the same terrain? The safest option would of course be to walk or rent a 4x4, but I'm going to assume that it's too long of a distance to do a) and OP cannot afford or does not want to do b). Neither option is super safe, yes, but if I was on a bumpy track I would much rather have 4 wheels than 2.

Comment: Scooters are also pretty notorious for not being safe. I think it's a safe bet that most people injuring or killing themselves on both kinds of vehicles have underestimated how dangerous they can be and overestimated how easy it will be for them to drive/ride them well. But I think they can be less cautious on a quadbike because they perceive them as being more inherently stable and thus safe. I would rather know objectively which is safer because after hearing of some bad accidents I don't trust the intuition on 4 wheels vs 2.

Comment: It might warrant a new question here. After searching briefly this is one good quote on the topic I've found so far: ["Quads can be even more dangerous than scooters, because they have a very high center of gravity. "](http://www.fodors.com/community/europe/scooterquadbike-rental-on-greek-islands.cfm)

Comment: Here's some more: ["The casualty rate for people who rent quad bikes is a simply astonishing 25%. That is **ONE IN FOUR**!"](http://nakedzante.com/the-zante-donts-how-not-to-die/) and here's a whole Reuters article with statistics and everything: [ATVs more deadly than motorcycles](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-atvs-motorcycles-idUSTRE6954RX20101006) with such quotes as "People may think that ATVs are less dangerous than motorcycles because they have four wheels. But really, the ATVs are probably more dangerous because the injuries people have after accidents are more deadly."

Comment: That might not simply be because of technical reasons. ATV's are more likely to be driven on rough terrain. A rocky or sandy track would be very difficult to traverse on a scooter, whether or not it is more dangerous, so many would probably turn around where someone on a quad would push on. Anyway, I did qualify my sentence with *probably*, whether or not it is safer it still may be a more practical solution, roads on Greek islands (particularly around isolated beaches) are often sandy, rocky and generally unpaved, which a scooter would struggle on.

Comment: @Crazymoomin No, it's because people have a false sense of security about quadbikes. Quadbikes require skill and training to ride safely, but people look at them, see four wheels and think "What could possibly go wrong?"

Comment: @David Richerby Plenty of tourists ride scooters without any formal training as well, they only have a car licence. You always get the idiots who ride them in a way they'd never do in a car. I've ridden quad bikes a few times with perhaps 15 minutes of training total with no problems, you just have to be sensible. Honestly I would recommend a quad over a scooter to anyone who has no experience with powered two wheeled vehicles. It's typically impractical and expensive to hire a car over there, and hot weather and distance inhibits walking or cycling. Buses only go to main destinations.